# 16.04: Apache2 and php not working!

Tags: 16.04, apache2.4, php7

Everytime I reinstall apache2 it just doesnt work WORKS. 
   `sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"`  gives `Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)`

Also while trying to install php7.0-mbstring, i get this error:

```
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-mbstring : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1) but 7.0.6-13+donate.sury.org~xenial+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I have tried to follow the instructions on how to fix broken packages but even tht has not helped. Hope someone can atleast help me find the right fault.

.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

This is no error, use `sudo ufw status` to check it, it simply tells you that a rule for that already exists.

Best is to get a bit familiar with `ufw` on command line by reading the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/ufw.8.html)

As for the second problem you added, make sure you enable the package sources in `System Settings --> Software & Updates` then run an:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Running the first and third command mostly keeps you out of trouble when trying to install something new. As well you only need to use `php-mbstring` thats the virtual package for the installation. So this will suffice:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I had exactly the same problem.
My answer is not very clean but it does work.

- First I installed aptitude: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`
- Then I asked aptitude to install php-mbstring: `sudo aptitude install php-mbstring`
- It asked me to make some choices to install it, so I didn't accept the first one (that was, "don't install php-mbstring"), I accepted the second one that was "downgrade a bunch of php modules to the right one
- **Now I have php-mbstring**

\o/